# Read unknown length by DataReader

Tags: c#, sockets

I've been working with windows app store programming in c# recently, and I've come across a problem with sockets.
I need to be able to read data with an unknown length from a `DataReader()`.

It sounds simple enough, but I've not been able to find a solution after a few days of searching.

Here's my current receiving code (A little sloppy, need to clean it up after I find a solution to this problem. And yes, a bit of this is from the Microsoft example)

```
DataReader reader = new DataReader(args.Socket.InputStream);
try
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Read first 4 bytes (length of the subsequent string).
        uint sizeFieldCount = await reader.LoadAsync(sizeof(uint));
        if (sizeFieldCount != sizeof(uint))
        {
            // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data.
            return;
        }

        reader.InputStreamOptions

        // Read the string.
        uint stringLength = reader.ReadUInt32();
        uint actualStringLength = await reader.LoadAsync(stringLength);
        if (stringLength != actualStringLength)
        {
            // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data.
            return;
        }

        // Display the string on the screen. The event is invoked on a non-UI thread, so we need to marshal
        // the text back to the UI thread.
        //MessageBox.Show("Received data: " + reader.ReadString(actualStringLength));
        MessageBox.updateList(reader.ReadString(actualStringLength));
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    // If this is an unknown status it means that the error is fatal and retry will likely fail.
    if (SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
    {
        throw;
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Read stream failed with error: " + exception.Message);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's related to `[tag:rt]`?

Comment: What is the problem? What happens? What are you sending?

Comment: Well the goal is to be able to send an unknown number of characters through the socket, then read all of the characters with the DataReader. Because this is a windows "app," most of the solutions I've found are incompatible.
With this current use of DataReader, there needs to be an integer appended to the front of the buffer indicating how many bytes the buffer actually is, as you can see in `uint stringLength = reader.ReadUInt32();`.
For my current purposes, I can't have that.

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're trying to do I think you've set yourself an impossible task.  How will any code at the receiving end know when the message has been received?  Let's say you've received n bytes so far.  Does that mean you've received the whole message?  Or just the first n bytes of a longer message?  Or even the whole message plus some bytes of some subsequent message?

Comment: Ok, fine I see what you're getting at. But on a vague, inspirational note, I'll have to bring up the fact that nothing is impossible. On a more logical note, I've been working with winsock recently and it seems to have a nice method of reading a null terminated buffer of undefined length. If winsock can do it, I'm inclined to believe there is a way, clean or dirty, for me to accomplish my goal. (or there could be an equally large chance that someone offers me an extremely technical reason I can't do this. Either way...)

Comment: Well guys, I was able to get this done (the dirty way) by reading one byte at a time until an exception is thrown. I feel there's a better way to do it, but... I guess this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going down the right lines  -  read the first INT to find out how many bytes are to be sent.

[Franky Boyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654614/frank-boyne) is correct - without a signalling mechanism it is impossible to ever know the length of a stream.  Thats why it is called a stream!

NO socket implementation (including the WinSock) will ever be clever enough to know when a client has finished sending data.  The client could be having a cup of tea half way through sending the data!

Your server and its sockets will never know!  What are they going to do?  Wait forever?  I suppose they could wait until the client had 'closed' the connection?  But your client could have had a blue screen and the server will never get that TCP close packet, it will just be sitting there thinking it is getting more data one day?

I have never used a DataReader - i have never even heard of that class!  Use NetworkStream instead.

---

From my memory I have written code like this in the past.  I am just typing, no checking of syntax.

```
using(MemoryStream recievedData = new MemoryStream())
{
    using(NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(connectedSocket))
    {
        int totalBytesToRead = networkStream.ReadByte();
        // This is your mechanism to find out how many bytes
        // the client wants to send.

        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024]; // Up to you the length!



        int totalBytesRead = 0;
        int bytesReadInThisTcpWindow = 0;
        // The length of the TCP window of the client is usually
        // the number of bytes that will be pushed through
        // to your server in one SOCKET.READ method call.


        // For example, if the clients TCP window was 777 bytes, a:

        // int bytesRead = 
        //          networkStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, int.Max);

        //    bytesRead would be 777.

        // If they were sending a large file, you would have to make
        // it up from the many 777s.

        // If it were a small file under 777 bytes, your bytesRead
        // would be the total small length of say 500.

        while
        (
            (
                bytesReadInThisTcpWindow =
                      networkStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)
            ) > 0
        )
            // If the bytesReadInThisTcpWindow = 0 then the client
            // has disconnected or failed to send the promised number
            // of bytes in your Windows server internals dictated timeout
            // (important to kill it here to stop lots of waiting
            // threads killing your server)
        {
            recievedData.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesReadInThisTcpWindow);
            totalBytesToRead = totalBytesToRead + bytesReadInThisTcpWindow;
        }

        if(totalBytesToRead == totalBytesToRead)
        {
            // We have our data!
        }
    }
}
```