# UWP TCP server memory overflow exception

Tags: c#, tcp, uwp

I'm building a TCP server in UWP to receive and send data from an NodeMCU (Arduino based) to an windows PC (later it will be a Raspberry Pi with Windows 10 IOT).

When setting up and startig the server there is no problem, and also the NodeMCU is changing the status to "connected" - it seems that the connection between PC and NodeMCU works just fine.

When receiving the data, I get an exception in the event handler, becaust the size (variable size in the code below) of the package is read as "1414743380" which is way too much and so I get an exception "Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program." at line "await reader.LoadAsync((uint)size);" which seems just right.

The variable payloadsize contains this:

[image]

The question is why do I get such a package size and where does it come from? 
Is there something wrong on the NodeMCU / Arduino side?

I used the code for the TCP Server from the [Microsoft Example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-networkhelper/blob/master/NetworkHelper/TcpCommunicationChannel.cs).

Starting the server:

```
    public async Task<bool> StartListeningAsync()
    {
        if (_localSocket == null)
        {
            _localSocket = new StreamSocketListener();
            _localSocket.ConnectionReceived += LocalSocketConnectionReceived;
            await _localSocket.BindServiceNameAsync(CommunicationPort);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Event handler for TCP messages:

```
    private async void LocalSocketConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        using (var reader = new DataReader(args.Socket.InputStream))
        {
            reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.None;

            // Read the length of the payload that will be received.
            byte[] payloadSize = new byte[(uint)BitConverter.GetBytes(0).Length];
            await reader.LoadAsync((uint)payloadSize.Length);
            reader.ReadBytes(payloadSize);

            // Read the payload.
            int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(payloadSize, 0);
            byte[] payload = new byte[size];
            await reader.LoadAsync((uint)size);
            reader.ReadBytes(payload);
        }
    }
```

the message from the Arduino is this (from Wireshark):
[image]

EDIT: Full message description
[image]

Comment: It looks like the Arduino isn't sending the byte count at beginning of message.  TCP will have two headers IP Header (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header) and TCP Header(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol).

Comment: is there a way to debug this? If I check the message in Wireshark everything looks fine. I've added the full frame in the question.

Comment: If I'm setting the size manually to "2" I can receive the command "\r\n" or in hex: 13 and 10. If I set the size to 3 - I get an exception that I'm accessing the wrtong memory. So it seems that the byte size is not correct.

Comment: Actually if cou convert the variable payloadsize (as in the picture above) to hex it contains exactly "TEST" - so it contains the first four bytes of the data section.
Do I need to send the length of the data package manually in the first four bytes?

Comment: OK, It seems I'm comming closer. There is a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374330/read-unknown-length-by-datareader).
For receiving the data with DateReader I need to send the package size in the firt four bytes.

Comment: You won't be able to receive data unless it is sent correctly.  So use sniffer results and verify the message length in the TCP data before trying to read the data.  Adding bytes to the TCP without changing the IP Header which has a size and the TCP header which also has a size will generate additional errors.

Comment: TCP socket doesn't provide you with the payload size. What I do is send the payload size in the first 8 bytes (long) and the receiver would read the first 8 bytes, convert it to a long and then starts reading the rest of the payload.

Comment: I just saw the link u posted. it is better to use Int64 (long) than using Int32 if you are sending large files over.

Comment: @Rafael Thanks for the explanation. Sending the payload size in the firt four bytes works for me. (I'm only sending text commands to the client).
But it was really hard for me to figure out this behavior (since this is the first time programming a TCP connection). Is there any documentation for this in the DataReader?

Comment: @ChristophH I couldn't find any good documentation on the data writer/reader except the one in ms docs website. The idea of sending the size was in a post in stackoverflow and not in some documentation.